# Having Issue on Deleting/ Removing Row From DataTables Permanenty

Tags: javascript, datatables

Can you please take a look at **[this demo](https://jsfiddle.net/Behseini/5sb9uya6/)** and let me know why I am not able to remove a row from dataTables table?

For example in the demo I am trying to Remove/Delete the Third Inserted row into the table by

```
$('#deleteRow').on( 'click', function () {
  $('tr').eq(4).remove();
} );
```

but as soon as I add a new row the removed row also appears in the table!

Can you please let me know what I am doing wrong and how I can fix this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Always* go through the API! Use

```
$('#deleteRow').on( 'click', function () {
   t.row(2).remove().draw();
} );
```

Instead. `row(2)` because you want to delete the third row, and row indexes is zero based. updated fiddle -> **https://jsfiddle.net/5sb9uya6/1/**

Answer (score 0):

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/5sb9uya6/2/)

> Please be aware that this method removes the data from the table
>   internally but that action won't be visually shown until the draw()
>   method is called to update the display. This method can called simply
>   as a chained method of the rows().remove() method's returned object -
>   for example table.rows().remove().draw();. This method is used to
>   reduce the number of draws required if multiple rows are being deleted
>   for optimisation.

[Source](https://datatables.net/reference/api/row%28%29.remove%28%29)

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
    var t = $('#example').DataTable();

    var counter = 1;
    $('#addRow').on('click', function () {

        t.row.add([
        counter + '.1',
        counter + '.2',
        counter + '.3',
        counter + '.4',
        counter + '.5']).draw(false);

        counter++;
    });

    $('#deleteRow').on('click', function () {
        var ind=$('tbody > tr:last').index();
       t.rows(ind).remove().draw()
    });


});
```